# Orthogonal basis for $L_2[0, 1]$ based on the eigenvalues of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Can someone help me out with this question?
Define the linear operator $T : L_2[0, 1] \rightarrow L_2[0, 1]$ by
$$Tf(x) = \int_0^x \int_y^1 f(z)dzdy$$
Find an orthogonal basis for $L_2[0, 1]$ based on the eigenvalues of this operator.

Comment: Hint: since an eigenvector must be smooth, try differentiating the equation $Tf=\lambda f$ to obtain a differential equation

Comment: @Caffeine Hi. Why would an eigenvector be smooth?